# prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})dt =0$

Tags: calculus

I want to show that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})dt =0.
\end{equation*}
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$\int_0^x\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi}{t}\bigg)dt = \int_0^x {t^2 \over \pi}\bigg({\pi \over t^2}\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi}{t}\bigg)\bigg)dt$$
Integrating the right-hand side by parts gives
$$-{x^2 \over \pi}\cos\bigg({\pi \over x}\bigg) + \int_0^x {2t \over \pi} \cos\bigg({\pi \over t}\bigg)\,dt$$
So 
$${\int_0^x\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})dt \over x} = -{x \over \pi}\cos\bigg({\pi \over x}\bigg) + {1 \over x}\int_0^x {2t \over \pi} \cos\bigg({\pi \over t}\bigg)\,dt$$
As $x$ goes to zero the first term goes to zero.

Since $|t \cos\big({\pi \over t}\big)| \leq |x|$, the integral in the second term is of absolute value at most ${2 \over \pi}x^2$, so the second term has absolute value at most ${2 \over \pi}|x|$. Hence as $x \rightarrow 0$ the second term goes to zero as well and we see that the overall limit is zero.

Answer (score 2):

We may just exploit:
$$\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right)\,dt=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{\sin(\pi u)}{u^2}\,du=\frac{2(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
that follows from integration by parts.

Comment: Why does Lhopital fail?

Comment: @grdgfgr Because $\sin(\pi/x)$ does not converge as $x \to 0^+$. In fact, $\int_0^x \sin(\pi/t) dt$ is continuous but not differentiable at $x$. The point of the problem is that even though it doesn't converge, "morally" it oscillates "evenly" between $-1$ and $1$, in such a way that "everything cancels out" on a small interval $[0,\delta]$.

Comment: If decide that oscillation cancels the solution, lhopital also works.

Comment: @grdgfgr No, it doesn't. You need the derivative of $\int_0^x \sin(\pi/t) dt$ to exist at zero and it just doesn't.

Comment: Why can't it be $\sin (\pi /x)$

Comment: @grdgfgr: l'Hopital's theorem has some hypothesis that are not fulfilled here, hence we have to tear down this problem by more low-tech ways, i.e. estimations on small sub-intervals of the integration range.

Comment: I have $$\frac{\int_0^x\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})dt}{x}$$ I take the derivative of num and denum $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$$ If oscillations "cancel", this limit is also 0.

Comment: @grdgfgr: the issue is that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ does not exist.

Comment: @grdgfgr The oscillations cancel when you add up the values in the integral. They don't cancel until then. (Also, "at $x$" in my first comment should have been "at $0$").

Answer (score 0):

The change of variables $t= 1/s$ gives

$$(1)\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{x}\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\sin \pi s}{s^2}\, ds.$$ Integrate by parts to see (1) equals $$ \frac{1}{x}\left [ x^2 \cos (\pi/x)/\pi - 2\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\cos \pi s}{\pi s^3}\,ds\right ]$$

In absolute value, the last integrand is no larger than $1/(\pi s^3),$ which is simple to integrate. It follows that (1) is $O(x)$ as $x \to 0^+.$